# Azure Devops disable concurrent runs on the same pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am have 2 build agents and 8 pipelines in azure devops. If a run starts for pipeline A, and another run is triggered for the same pipeline Azure Devops will start a second run on the other agent without waiting for the first to finish.

How do I make Azure Devops wait until the first run is finished before starting the second one?

Edit: using yaml pipelines rather than old build/release pipelines.

Comment: Why does it matter to you? Builds should be stateless.

Comment: It's common in other CI such as jenkins to run end to end tests against a test environment before deploying to the next environment in the pipeline. So you want to prevent another version being deployed over this one until the pipeline as finished.

Comment: That would happen in a release pipeline, not a build. Releases have mechanisms to control the degree of parallelism.

Comment: I'm using the new yaml pipelines rather than old build/release pipelines

Comment: @DanielMann surely you would want to run all tests in the build pipeline before creating releases to deploy to manual test / staging enviornment?

Comment: There is a community request for this feature that you can vote on: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365730/prevent-parallel-execution-of-the-same-build-defin.html.

Comment: Consider terraform with backend storage in Azure Storage Container (very common).  The Container is Lease Locked, so concurrent pipelines will result in failure when second+ pipeline `terraform init` cannot lock the state file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use adding **demands** to the pool on the agent job of pipelines, so that it will run with one same agent because of the same specified condition.

First, add one **Capability** in the agent.

[image]

And then, in your YAML, add demands to the pool.

```
pool:
  name: {agent pool name}
  demands: Limit -equals DisAbleParallel
```

The format of it is `demands:{CapabilityName} -equals {CapabilityValue}`.

While you specified the agent demands, the pipeline will just run with this agent. While A is running, the second one will not run at same time because the previous is running, the agent is being using. So that, the second one will run until previous ends.

Comment: This will limit one job at a time. But I need to queue the whole Run. Only have one Run at a time.

Comment: "Demands are only applicable when your pipeline runs on self-hosted agents."

Comment: This will not limit the parallel job execution on an agent having "Limit=DisableParallel" , only help to select a specific agent from a pool of agents.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to do this (prevent a stage from being executed by multiple builds at the same time) by doing the following:

1. Create a protected resource in Azure. I chose a variable group named `build_concurrency_lock`. You can add it via `Pipelines` -> `Library` -> `Variable Groups`. Be sure to add an "Exclusive Lock" to the resource.

[image: adding an Exclusive Lock]

2. Then add this to the stage to run serially within `azure-pipelines.yml`.

```yaml
stages:
  # Code Pipeline
  - stage: BuildStage
    displayName: "Build"

    # These next three lines make builds run in serial. We need to do this since we use a shared "builds" environment in azure - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73694320/1072030, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml, and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-190-update#support-for-sequential-deployments-rather-than-latest-only-when-using-exclusive-lock-checks
    lockBehavior: sequential
    variables:
      - group: build_concurrency_lock # relies on a "build_concurrency_lock" Library variable group existing and having an "Exclusive Lock" "Approvals and checks" setup.
```

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you can do this by using the trigger options in the yaml file:

```
trigger:  
    batch: true
```

Do note that this value is false by default (so when left empty), but it might only be when a trigger has been defined?

Docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#triggers

Comment: According to docs that is not the default behavior.

Comment: You are correct @Monsignor: the default recently changed. Updated the answer

Comment: This doc more clearly describes "batch: true" behavior. <br/>

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#batching-ci-runs

Comment: This doesn't actually disable concurrent build runs, just staggers builds. This answer helped for the OP's use-case. It doesn't address the titled question or doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Preventing concurrent runs may be done by setting up an environment with an Exclusive Lock check. That allows working with Microsoft-hosted agents, not just self-hosted agents. It also does not require pipelines to be assigned to specific agents the way Demands do.

1. In Pipelines/Environments define an environment, say "my_environment".
   [image: ADO nav bar image]
2. To the environment add a check of type "Exclusive Lock".
3. In your YAML, reference environment "my_environment" using this form:

```
    lockBehavior: sequential
    stages:
    - stage: Stage
      jobs:
      - deployment: Job
        environment: my_environment
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                ...
```

This will force multiple queues of the same pipeline to run sequentially in queue order.
Different pipelines must use different environments, otherwise they will block each other.

More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-190-update#azure-pipelines-1

Comment: this doesn't process them in order though
> the check cancels all the old runs and permits the latest run to be deployed.

Answer (score 0):

The linked-to PowerShell Task works well. I personally set the sleep polling to 60 seconds but other than that this works with one main exception. It won't work if they're queued simultaneously or within a similar starting time. If more than one build is queued before this task completes when no jobs are actually building yet, it will just get stuck until cancelled or times out.

That means if you can wait for a minute or two before building, this will work.

- I don't recommend it for large teams all working on the same repository.
- I also don't recommend it for incredibly long builds. I'm not sure, but I think the max timeout for builds is 360 minutes. So if they're long and queued up in numbers you'll risk chain-failures.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/prevent-parallel-execution-of-the-same-build-defin/365730#T-N859271